# MonoTouch.Dialog equivalent for Objective C?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

Is there an equivalent of [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Feb-23.html), but for native Objective C apps? MonoTouch.Dialog automatically generates UITableView settings-style interfaces based on model metadata, or via a simple API.

I've been experimenting with building apps with MonoTouch, but I've found the app startup time currently unacceptable, so I'm trying to move to the Proper One True Apple Way.

I know about InAppSettingsKit, but that seems to be specifically for replicating the Settings.app interface, whereas MonoTouch.Dialog can generate much more flexible interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternate available called QuickDialog. It is very stable and actively developed. I used it in projects and highly recommend it.

You can clone the code repository from Github here https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog